# Setting a global variabel and reading it

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm creating a international program, so I need multiple languages in it. On the first screen I have a button with a flag on it, when clicking that flag, it knows the language and what file he needs to read.
For example: if you click the dutch flag it will read a file with Dutch sentences. It will fill the vector with the sentences, later on I use the vector to set the labels/buttons etc to the right language.

The thing is, im using multiple forms and I want to tell my other forms, the language = DUTCH, set the text in the labels/buttons into Dutch. But I need a global variable to work with that.

So my question is: How can I set a global variable?

I need a string thats just saying: "Dutch" or "English".

And I need a global vector for the lines of the file.

MainScreen.h:

```
extern std::string Global_Language;
extern std::vector<std::string> Global_VectorLanguage;
```

MainScreen.cpp:

```
std::string Global_Language = "English"; // since it's by default English

void __fastcall TMainForm::btnLanguageDutchClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMainForm::SetLanguage("Dutch", "Nederlands.txt");
}

void __fastcall TMainForm::btnLanguageEnglishClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMainForm::SetLanguage("English", "English.txt");
}

void TMainForm::SetLanguage(string a_Language, string a_fileName)
{
   string line;
   ifstream myfile;

   Global_VectorLanguage.resize(100);
   int Index = 0;
   myfile.open(a_fileName.c_str());

   if (myfile.is_open())
   {
        while(getline(myfile, line))
       {
           Global_VectorLanguage[Index] = line;
           Index++;
       }
    myfile.close();

   Global_Language = a_Language;
   MainForm->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[0].c_str();
   lblHPI->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[1].c_str();
   lblPhoneNo->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[2].c_str();
   lblEmail->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[3].c_str();
   btnStart->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[4].c_str();
   btnStop->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[5].c_str();
   btnResetEmergency->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[6].c_str();
   gboxLicenseInfo->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[7].c_str();
   lblName->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[8].c_str();
   lblVersion->Caption = Global_VectorLanguage[9].c_str();

   }
}
```

ManualScreen.cpp:

```
__fastcall TManualForm::TManualForm(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
   if(Global_Language == "Dutch")
   {
     //set labels/buttons to Dutch

   }
}
```

Comment: Just... do it? Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I guess your problem is how to localize the languages? Just use the name of the language in the language itself. E.g. "Français" instead of "French" or "Deutsch" instead of "German". So people will understand what language to select. Your users won't be happy to search for 英語

Comment: Well my question is HOW do I create a global variable? and about the language showing, I just use a bitbutton with the flag of the country on it :)

Comment: @Bart: please improve your question by showing actual real C++ code chunks.

Comment: Show also the compiler command and error messages.

Comment: I've edited it, but I didnt declare the vector in the Mainscreen.cpp, did that now and now it's fine. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(What you are caring about is [internationalization & localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) and your operating system might have support for that, see e.g. [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html), [setlocale(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html), [gettext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html) etc... on Linux and with C++11 [`<locale>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale) standard header)

You might declare a *few* global variables as `extern` in some header file and defile it in *one* source file.

E.g. in your `header.h` file a declaration:

```
extern std::string my_global_lang;
```

and in your `localization.cc` file a definition:

```
std::string my_global_lang{"English"};
```

However you often should prefer declaring a `static` variable inside some `class` (so called a [*class variable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable)).

```
class MyLocalization {
  static std::string global_lang;
  /// etc...
};
```

Then use `MyLocalization::global_lang`

Having many global variables or static member variables is considered poor style. Generally, a program should have few global variables (less than you have fingers on one hand). You might prefer packing state into explicit instances of some `class`, perhaps declaring some [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) `class ProgramState;` and have one instance of it created early in your `main`; the [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) class of Qt could inspire you.

I strongly recommend enabling all warnings & debug info when compiling (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and reading some good [C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and [sites](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). We cannot teach you the basics of C++ programming (which *is* difficult) here.

Comment: Ok, I've added `extern std::string Global_Language;` to my MainScreen.h. I declared it in MainScreen.cpp. But when I use Global_Language in another cpp file it says: Illegal structure operation.

Comment: @Bart: you should improve your question (or asking another one) by editing it to show your code.

Comment: Oh nvm, the error I had was a little typo. But I got it fixed, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You handle global variables just like you do local variables. The difference is mainly where the variable is declared. Just try something like:

```
#include <string>
std::string language = "English";

int main(void)
{
    ...
    if (/*user changes language to Dutch*/)
    {
        if (language == "English")
            language = "Dutch";
        else
            language = "English";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I declare it in the .h file?

Comment: @Bart No, this will lead to linker errors (if the h file is included in multiple cpp files = multiple compilation units, there would be multiple global variables with the same name). To make the var accessible in other files, you can make a `extern` declaration in the h file.